# jQuery fullcalendarについて

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

fullcalendarとMysqlを連動してアプリケーションを作成しております。

月の切り替えボタン（前月、次月）クリック時に、その月のイベントを
切り替えて描画したいのですが、どのように実装すればよろしいでしょうか？

1.最初の表示→12月一覧のデータを取得
2.ボタンで月を切り替える→切り替えた月のイベント一覧を取得し再描画

すいませんが、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: どのような取得データが返ってくるか、また動かなかったサンプルコードなどがあれば貼付けていただくと、解決が早まるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
イベント自体は取得できたのですが、新たな問題があります。
var get_start_date;
var get_end_date;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
viewRender: function(view, element) {
　　get_start_date = '20141205130000';
    get_end_date   = '20141205140000';
}

events: 'json-events.php?start=20141205130000&end=20141205140000',
})

上記でjson-events.phpにgetで値を送りつけているのですが、
getでうまくパラメータを取得できていないようです。

php側は
 $start = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($_GET('start')));
としています。
＊取り急ぎエスケープなどは考慮せず書いております。

Comment: すいません。自己解決しました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

jQuery fullCalendar では、[events オプション](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)を設定することで、ajax からのイベントの読み込みが行えます。

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'myfeed.php'
});
```

詳細は[マニュアル](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)にある通りですが、PHPの場合、以下のようなスクリプトでイベントを返せばいいかと思います。

```
<?php
// myfeed.php

// jQuery FullCalendar はデフォルトでGETパラメータstart, endにYYYY-MM-DD形式で範囲を渡す
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['start']);
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['end']);

$start->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$end->setTime(23, 59, 59);

// Querying Events ...
// $events = $db->query(
//     'SELECT * FROM events WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ?',
//     $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
//     $end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
// );

// ...and Output
echo json_encode(
    array(
        array('start' => '2014-12-12', 'title' => 'イベント1'),
        array('start' => '2014-12-22', 'title' => 'イベント2'),
    )
);
```

Comment: サンプルまで送って頂きありがとうございます。
これをヒントに進めていきたいと思います。